# Jquery commenting, using ColdFusion and Access

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

I am trying to figure out why this is not posting to my database. When I hit Post Comment. Everything disappears as if it posted the comments but instead it doesnt do anything. Any help would be well appreciated. Thanks! I am not sure what else is missing.

```
       <html>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js">    
</script>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#addcomment").click(function () 
        $("#postComment").show("slow");
    });
});
    </script>

        <cfform name="InsertComments" id="InsertComments">
<div id="container">
    <div id="mainContent">
      <div id="addcomment"> <a href='#'>add comment</a></div>
        <div id='postComment'>
            <textarea name='comment' id='comment'></textarea>
            <input type='text' id='Image_ID'''></input type>
            <input type='submit' value='Post Comment' />
        </div>
    </div>  
    </cfform>
        <cfif IsDefined("form.InsertComments")>
                <cfif IsDefined("form.InsertComments")>
                    <cfquery datasource="AccessTest">
                        INSERT INTO CommentsDB (Remarks, Image_ID, Date_Time )
                        VALUES
                        (<cfqueryparam value="#form.comment#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_LONGVARCHAR">
                    </cfqueryparam>
                        , <cfqueryparam value="#form.Image_ID#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
                    </cfqueryparam>
                        , <cfqueryparam value="#now()#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp">
                    </cfqueryparam>
                        )
                    </cfquery>
                </cfif>
            </cfif>
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: FYI, rolled back to original version, because the "solution" is meaningless without the original "question" ;-) Better to post the final code as a separate answer instead. You can still select Dan's response as the answer, if it led you to the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cfif tag is looking for a form field named InsertComments.  Your form does not have a field named InsertComments.  The only field it has is called comment.

In fact, you probably don't even have any form fields.  Your cfform tag does not specify the method and the default is "get".  That produces url variables, not form variables.

Set debugging to on so you can see what variables you do have.

Comment: *the default is "get".* You are probably thinking of `<form>`. However, `<cfform>` defalts to `method="post"`.

Comment: I did say probably.  I always specify a method so I wouldn't have a reason to care.

Comment: Lol, but *your* practices are not the subject in question here ;-)